# asking help for optimizing my auto keyboard presser in python

Tags: python

I don't fully understand about coding and optimizing codes, I just know little bit python.

I wrote a code in python which helps to climb walls in a game. But it isn't optimized. So could somebody help to optimize and improve my code? By the way I couldn't find much informations about libraries so I don't remember how I wrote code. I just put codes what I can find into my. It was complicated process.

My purpose of code is when I press ' *o* ', code will do key combination that is ' **0.13 second left, 0.01 second up, 0.001 second rigth** ', when ' *p* ' is pressed code will do ' **0.13 second right, 0.01 second up, 0.001 second left** '. By the way It will do combinations as long as I pressed ' *o* ' or ' *p* '.

Here is my code;

```
import pyautogui
import time
import keyboard

#Click function presses a key in a given time
def click(key,z):
   pyautogui.keyDown(key)
   time.sleep(z)
   pyautogui.keyUp(key)
   return

#Right key combination function
def right():
   i = True
       
   while i:
      click('right',0.13)
      click('up',0.01)
      click('left',0.001)
      i = keyboard.is_pressed('p')
      print(i,"right")
      if not i:
         break

#Left key combination function
def left():
   i = True
   while i:
      click('left',0.13)
      click('up',0.01)
      click('right',0.001)
      i = keyboard.is_pressed('o')
      print(i,"left")
      if not i:
         break

#Main execution part             
if __name__ == "__main__":
   #Time for switch to game
   time.sleep(3)
   i = True
   while i:
      if keyboard.is_pressed('p'):
         right()
      elif keyboard.is_pressed('o'):
         left()
      elif keyboard.is_pressed('esc'):
         break
      time.sleep(0.015)
```

Comment: If your code works properly, you should ask this in [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: How can I ask it in code rewiew

Comment: You also have multiple questions here.  You should limit yourself to one question per post.  Here are some basics: to compile into an exe, look into PyInstaller. Programming follows a flow. Optimizing means limiting the number of steps the program takes.  Your code is pretty tight.  However, you maywant to look into how sleep works. It may not be precise enough to deliver the type of millisecond timing you are looking for.

Comment: I removed extra question